# What is this plane with its thick cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Today I saw this unusual plane while going to work. I'm in France, near Paris. It flew at a rather low altitude, even if I can't tell precisely - I noticed the low altitude because of the loud sound.

We have an airport at 20km, the Charles de Gaulle Airport (CDG).
The plane was going towards South-West, probably directly departing from it. It came from this direction.
I was in the place named "La Défense", a district in the west of Paris.

I did make an outline sketch but it's not very precise : [image: three images of the plane with a broad nose, one head-on, one in profile and one form above.]

It looked like a very small airliner; what sparked my attention was the front of the plane (the cockpit, very probably), which was thicker than the fuselage, making it look like some sort of hammerhead shark.
The wings were posistioned more towards the back of the fuselage than usual, but I can't remember if they were straight or oriented like usual.
As well it had a T-shaped tail.

I'm not very knowledgeable about planes but I have a some interest and I have never seen one like this.

I'm curious because it really looked unusual to me and that cockpit was funny.

Comment: Could it be just a canard instead of a large cockpit ?

Comment: I have tried to confirm my answer about the Avanti using flight tracking websites, but have not had luck so far. Could you narrow down the time window, geographic area or direction of flight?

Comment: I didn't know about these "canards". Indeed this could probably it, It was difficult to tell. 
I'll add details about the flight

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has mentioned [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/). I saw a strange plane over my house, noted the time, and later looked up arrivals around that time at the nearby airport. My strange plane happened to be the same type of plane in the accepted answer.

Comment: @TKK nice tool, thank you for the recommandation

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Potentially a [Piaggio Avanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaggio_P.180_Avanti), based on OPs description of an unusual nose.

[image]

[image]

Comment: + Avanti fits perfectly with "loud sound" description

Comment: this really looks like it ! I'll wait a little but I thing you got it